# Segfault on loading a dylib with a constructor - only in Release builds

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, debugging, dylib

I'm writing a dynamic library in Objective-C, and recently I started experiencing a very strange issue, where loading the dylib triggers a segfault crash as soon as it's loaded. The trouble is, this only occurs in Release builds - Debug builds work just fine. Here's an example of the relevant stack trace in the crash:

```
Terminating due to signal Segmentation fault: 11; backtrace: (
    0   <redacted>.dylib                    0x003417a9 SignalHandler + 52
    1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x39cded33 _sigtramp + 34
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x31abaac9 CFRelease + 1104
    3   ???                                 0x2ff07629 0x0 + 804288041
    4   ???                                 0x2ff04a39 0x0 + 804276793
    5   ???                                 0x2ff04875 0x0 + 804276341
    6   ???                                 0x2fefdfff 0x0 + 804249599
    7   ???                                 0x2ff01a47 0x0 + 804264519
    8   libdyld.dylib                       0x39c97949 dlopen + 48
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x31b31b11 <redacted> + 116
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x31b067cb _CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError + 418
    11  Foundation                          0x32424159 <redacted> + 848
```

I experimented with the code a bit and narrowed down the source of the crash to a single constructor in my code. When this constructor is removed, the crash no longer occurs. But if I do so much as include a `printf` statement in the constructor, the crash reappears. Something as simple as this triggers it:

```
static void __attribute__((constructor)) TestConstructor() {
    printf("THIS IS A TEST");
}
```

I should also mention that I do have other constructor functions in other files (all declared statically), and each of those works fine. It's *this particular constructor* that is causing the crash, and that's what really confuses me.

Any ideas? I'm not sure how to debug it further from here.

Comment: only in release builds you say ... edit your targets build options to use the same compiler optimization and symbol strapping settings for debug and release, and try to replicate it then. you issue sounds like the build process strips out some code it thinks unused